# Page height doesn't adapt to the page new content

Tags: html, css

First of all, I have zero experience with html/css and I'm trying to customize the astral html5up.net template, but I can't figure out how to solve this problem. That is, when I submit the contact form and
the error message appears (the pink one generated with php/jquery), the page height doesn't adapt to the page new content and this is the result:

After:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/313n5vd.jpg

Before:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/9scxs7.jpg

However it seems that switching to another page fixes the problem for the contact page. This is the code:

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
        <div id="wrapper">

          <!-- Cut out content -->

             <!-- Main -->
                <div id="main">

                <!-- Cut out content -->

                    <!-- Contact -->
                        <article id="contact" class="panel">
                            <header>
                                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                            </header>

                            <form id="formail" action="#" method="post">

                                <div id="reply">

                                <!-- Here is where the jquery error message appears -->

                                </div>

                                <!-- Cut out content -->
```

Where should I look to fix the problem? Maybe at this line in the css?

```
#main
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `max-height` on your container

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it were to explain how to set max-height and why that would help the asker's problem.